# (Reference Request) Family of Pairs of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

In tackling a question in analysis, the following subset of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ (pairs of $n \times n$ real matrices) showed up:

$$\{(A, B)\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid (A^{k} - B^{k})(A^{l} - B^{l}) = 0 \text{ }\forall\text{ }k, l \geq 1 \} $$

Can this set be described in a different, perhaps simpler way? Is there a specific name for this set in linear algebra, and if so, can one point me to a reference?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in what application does this appear?

Comment: @mathreadler This appeared in attempting to solve a question in dynamical systems.